# Как понять куда размещена переменная const в область флешь или озу

Tags: c, eclipse

Написал структуру такого типа:

```
typedef struct {
    const char name[20];
    const char textExtension[4];
    const uint32_t size;
    const uint32_t date;
    const uint32_t time;
    const uint32_t adrr;
    const uint32_t crc;
    const uint32_t reserve[5];
} headerFileList[256];
```

Все переменные const. Как понимаю должны быть размещены только во флешь, но как в этом убедиться, что они гарантированно там? Мне нужно только читать данные поля структуры, писать туда ничего не нужно.

Comment: есть опции защиты области памяти Read , Write , eXecute. Что такое у вас "флешь"?

Comment: флешь - ПЗУ (жесткий диск)

Comment: Любые переменные при запуске программы хранятся в оперативке. и в режиме RW. защиты нет.

Comment: const в режиме RW ?

Comment: const - это для удобства . Приведение типа и уже не конст.

Comment: если у вас Linux то есть фишки системной защиты памяти. И можно поставить флаг "ReadOnly" для страницы памяти.

Comment: При чем тут линукс?

Comment: @AlexGlebe, речь немножко про embedded. Как правило, это Гарвардская архитектура. Из-за ограниченности ресурсов (оперативная память) часто константы складывают в область кода программы (пзу, флэш или еще куда). Речь именно об этом, а не о том, где хранятся переменные в процессе выполнения программы. zhilenkov, Вы могли бы в тегах указать микроконтроллер, чтобы было меньше недопонимания. А по вопросу... если Вы не писали никаких атрибутов, то скорее всего в ОЗУ. Но это зависит от компилятора и микроконтроллера - читайте документацию на язык от производителя процессора.

Comment: Надежнее всего посмотреть в дизассемблере

Comment: Подскажите как с помощью атрибутов указать память во флешь?

Comment: В языке Си нет стандартного способа. Я могу только хакнуть через ассемблер : `.section    .rodata head: ...`

Comment: Читайте комментарий @Vladimir современные компиляторы засовывают всё в `.rodata` секцию. Можно создавать свои секции и с помошью скрипта линковщика уже располагать куда хочется.

Comment: есть способ заносить этот массив в строку (большую). А в Си эта строка будет только в коде исполняемого файла. И она не будет занимать место в памяти. Заморочка будет с двойной компиляцией, сначала создаётся файл с этой строкой, а потом можно будет уже компилировать всю прогу. Способны на двойную компиляцию?

Comment: @AlexGlebe это все уже лишнее.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сделать массив константных структур, и этот массив будет в секции только для чтения. Тогда скорее всего, память лишняя выделяться не будет. И данные будут храниться только в кеше системы.

```
# include <stdint.h>

typedef struct headerFile headerFile  ;

struct headerFile {
    char name[20];
    char textExtension[4];
    uint32_t size;
    uint32_t date;
    uint32_t time;
    uint32_t adrr;
    uint32_t crc;
    uint32_t reserve[5];
} ;

headerFile const headerFileArray [ 256 ] =
  {{"n","t",0,0,0,0,0,{0}}};

# include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  printf("headerFileArray[0].name=%s\n",headerFileArray[0].name);
  (*(char*)&(headerFileArray[0].name[0]))=0;
}
```

В ассемблере смотрим, вроде RO :

```
 ...
 .globl headerFileArray
 .section   .rodata
 .align 32
 .type  headerFileArray, @object
 .size  headerFileArray, 16384
headerFileArray:
 .string    "n"
 ...
```

проверка :

```
headerFileArray[0].name=n
Ошибка сегментирования (стек памяти сброшен на диск)
```

Проверил только через `gcc` компилятор. Как ведёт себя `eclipse` - не знаю. Надо вам самим проверять.

Answer (score 0):

В компиляторе gcc есть стандартные атрибуты  `section ("section-name")`

```
struct s_header_file_list{
    char name[20];
    char textExtension[4];
    uint32_t size;
    uint32_t date;
    uint32_t time;
    uint32_t adrr;
    uint32_t crc;
    uint32_t reserve[5];
};
 
struct s_header_file_list[256] __attribute__ ((section ("FLASH"))) = {0};
```

В файле линковки *.ld нужно указать в каком адресном пространстве находится секция `FLASH`